# Jupyter / IPython Notebook text editing as markdown

Tags: python, formatting, jupyter-notebook, italic

Hi all I'm starting a new Python 3 document in Jupyter, and when I tried to put the test in the center in a markdown, I put: 
`<h1><center> Whatever Report </center></h1>
<center> Based on the data from *January 1, 2018* </center>`

As you can see I tried to italicize the date, yet when I ran the command, `Based on the data from *January 1, 2018*`is printed as a result. Why aren't the texts being italicized?

Thanks much!

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use `<i>`, `</i>` tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not any kind of markdown expert, but it looks like the asterisks are not interpreted as italics when within an HTML tag. First one works, second does not.

```
<center>Based on the data from <i>January 1, 2018</i></center>
<center>Based on the data from *January 1, 2018*<center>
```

Not sure to format that output for SO. Ha.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your markdown in markdown cells, not embedded in html.
http://www.firstpythonnotebook.org/markdown/

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, just getting started with Jupyter and the guidance is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's very late, but you can try to use `$\unicode{x212B}$` and it will render as the right format. The original solution can be found at https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/795.